# JPA model update [1.1.1]

Tags: jpa, playframework

I'm sure this is something very simple, but for the life of me can't 
find the correct keywords on google.

Basically I've updated a couple models since my last deployment.  Dev is set up with the jpa.ddl default setting of create-drop.  Now I read that prod isn't supposed to run with jpa.ddl=update, so does that mean I have to manually script a schema change?  I couldn't find any documentation saying the correct way. I am also using playapps, so the database is set up there.  I set up ssl, so I should have sql access via command line.  However, I was having difficulty figuring out the syntax for modifying the db.  I'm so used to a gui environment such as phpMySQL or microsoft's sql server. The errors specifically I'm getting are the following two (when running the application after uploading to prod).

---

Unsuccessful: alter table PhotoSlide add index FK57E3FABF5C905145 (aPhoto_id), add constraint FK57E3FABF5C905145 foreign key (aPhoto_id) references StorePhoto (id)

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`play/#sql-2e29_32`, CONSTRAINT `FK57E3FABF5C905145` FOREIGN KEY (`aPhoto_id`) REFERENCES `StorePhoto` (`id`))

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that by using the migration module.More details you can find @
http://www.playframework.org/modules/migrate

The flow will be like the below:
You push new code to prod --> you run migrations --> restart the server

More documentation at : 
https://github.com/dcardon/play-migrate/blob/master/documentation/manual/home.textile

With the latest version  play supports migrations : 
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/evolutions

Comment: I did see this, but thought it was only helpful when starting off with the module - as opposed to using it mid project.  I will take a second look though and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Please read the stuff now play supports migrations without any additional modules @ http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/evolutions